# Permissions required for graph beta synchronization endpoint

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use a Service Principal and the ms graph api to call the beta [synchronization/jobs/](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/synchronization-synchronizationjob-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) endpoint but get a 401 Unauthorized error.

Now I know in the documentation it says I need the `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` or  `Directory.ReadWrite.All` scopes, but I would rather use role permissions assigned to the Service Principal to keep access more granular.

I've assigned the Principal to the application administrator role, this allows me to access [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{object-id}/](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/%7Bobject-id%7D/) but when I try [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{object-id}/synchronization/jobs/](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/%7Bobject-id%7D/synchronization/jobs/) I get a 401 code with

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-06-28T14:35:44",
      "request-id": "5c5532e5-b506-475b-b926-8b3ec36525d7",
      "client-request-id": "5c5532e5-b506-475b-b926-8b3ec36525d7"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there some role permission I'm missing or is this endpoint not compatible with role permissions yet? Or most likely am I being silly and missing something?

I've tried using the golang adal package and the `az account get-access-token --resource https://graph.microsoft.com` command to get a token.

I can access this endpoint when authenticated as my AAD user with Global admin role.

Answer (score 1):

The application permission of Microsoft Graph cannot be completely replaced by directory role permissions. They cannot replace each other.

Generally speaking, the permissions of the AAD Graph and the directory role permission have a certain overlap. But Microsoft Graph is not.

Please use Application permission `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` or `Directory.ReadWrite.All` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by adding following Microsoft Graph API permission `Application.ReadWrite.All` & `Directory.ReadWrite.All` for application which I used to authenticate and get Access_token.

Working API permission on my lab:
[image]

If any of these two permission missing then expected to get `(401) Unauthorized` same as you.
[image]